# How to change the Button color while mouse over

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a simple sample that contains a button.
I need to change the background when hovering the cursor over that button.

In Windows Phone it has `VisualStateManager` or triggers in WPF xaml but I don't know how to do it with Xamarin.Forms buttons.

```
<Button Background="Red" >
   ...
    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                               ...
    </VisualState>
</Button
```

Comment: You can use Triggers in Xamarin.Forms: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/triggers/, Event Trigger in particular for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you have to do this natively. Create a new Control and implement the renderers on the platforms with this behavior.

Comment: Thanks I have created the CustomRenderer using ButtonRenderer and modify the styles.